# IIS pool duplicates after appdomain restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We have an application which read messages from IBM MQ Topic and interact with users via SignalR WebSockets.

Case:

1. Open iis asp.net application web.config
2. Change and save it (this causing appdomain restart)
3. Repeate step 2 10 times

After that we can see many **Application_Start**/**Dispose** events in logs but at **ONE** of appdomain restart iterations haven't **Dispose** call. Cause that out IBM MQ listener handling message from old AppDomain therefore we have duplicate handling and business errors.

It seems like something constraint AppDomain from unload.

I know what it's very hard to say what's there happening, but maybe anybody knows how can we trace that problem.

**Disable Overlapped Recycle** is **true**

**Shutdown Time Limit** is **3s**

Comment: Old AppDomain may stay constrained a many hours

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing/ You might dig into ETW to see if you can get more info. It is called appdomain restart, not recycle, so please please edit your question to correct the misuse of the term.

Answer (score 0):

what I have do in similar situation - on `global.asax` use this call

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // here signaling the listener to close - and wait until they do
     // also raise the shutdown time limit to more than 3 seconds, give them time to close
}
```